# Implicit conversion from non-const to const template parameter does not work in boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost

Why does this code compile?

```
std::shared_ptr<const int> Bar()
{
    return std::make_shared<int>(123);
}
```

But this does not...

```
boost::optional<const int> Foo()
{    
    return boost::optional<int>(123);
}
```

I get the following error:

> could not convert 'boost::optional<int>(123)' from 'optional<int>' to
>   'optional<const int>'

Using gcc 6.3.0 and boost 1.65.1.

Comment: It's worth noting that this works fine with `std::optional`

Comment: `boost::optional<T const>`  doesn't seem very useful in the first place. It's a bit like returning `T const` from a function (`T const foo()`) or e.g. the fact that `void bar(int);`  and `void bar(int const);` are exactly the same function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/header_optional_optional_values.html#reference_operator_template)'s  converting constructors are marked explicit.  Therefore you cannot perform implicit conversion from `boost::optional<T>` to `boost::optional<U>`.  You can perform an explicit conversion:

```
boost::optional<const int> Foo()
{    
    return boost::optional<const int>(boost::optional<int>(123));
}
```

It's worth noting that [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) (which is added in C++17, and is based on boost's version) has converting constructors that are explicit only if the contained types are not implicitly convertible.  Therefore your `Foo` function would work as-is with `std::optional`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my confusion was down to thinking that implict qualification conversion would somehow also apply to template parameters. In retrospect, I realize that's absurd since boost::optional<int> and boost::optional<const int> are different types.

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` has explicit support so that this works. It doesn't just work in general.

`boost::optional` apparently does not have such support.